# How do I use "or" (|) operator in C# "object.equals"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, equals

```
var controllingContext = _context.Inventaris.Include(i => i.Artkl).Include(i => i.Status).Where(x => x.StatusId.Equals(stat[0] | stat[1]));
```

I am trying to add an or operator in C# to the object.equals method this was working while I didn't have the or operator in there and it was just checking for 1 item but now I added the or operator and it doesn't work anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing you mean to call `Equals` multiple times, OR'd together: `.Where(x => x.StatusId.Equals(stat[0]) || x.StatusId.Equals(stat[1]))`. If you want the bitwise or, use a single `|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to filter `StatusId` equals `stat[0]` or `stat[1]`. If so you just need to use OR(`||`) operator as following:

```
.Where(x => x.StatusId.Equals(stat[0]) || x.StatusId.Equals(stat[1]));
```

See [LINQ Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering)

Comment: Thanks! Working now! I'm a beginner haha. I'll accept the answer as soon as possibel (still have to wait 6 mins)